# Why is main.js defined twice in BoilerplateJS

Tags: boilerplatejs

Why is main.js defined in two locations in the BoilerplateJS project? It appears that only the one defined in the project's root directory is used and the one in the app directory is not. Could someone please clarify. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thought and figure other people would too. The main.js in the top level is used. The duplicate I think you're referring to inside the app sub-directory (app/main.js) doesn't appear to be used and is probably a left-over from development. In that same directory is app/application.js which is largely the same and what is kicked off from the parent main.js.